# I'm writing a code that takes a quantity input from the user for five items in a company

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

My problem is when the user enters a decimal value for the quantity of one of the items, the program ends automatically. What I need it to do, on the other hand, is to display a message letting the user know that they made a mistake and give them the option to try again.

I've tried using the cin.fail() function with no luck whatsoever.

```
 cout<< "\nEnter number of Whizbangs: ";
 cin>> WhizbangsAmt;
 //This screens out all the negative numbers
 while(true)
 {
     if(WhizbangsAmt < 0)
     {
         cout<< "Number is negative!\n";
         cout<< "Enter number of Whizbangs: ";
         cin>> WhizbangsAmt;
     }
     else
     {
         break;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Still, have no idea what you are *trying* to ask...

Comment: Probably you were using `cin.fail()` incorrectly. But instead of posting the code you are having trouble with you've posted the code that works. Please post your attempt using `cin.fail()`.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is incomprehensible. Consider using a function to read Integers instead of using the raw `std::cin` function. 
By using `unsigned int` you are able to se the first bit of your integer, thus you choose the algebraic sign.

```
unsigned int readInt(std::istream& stream) {
    /*
     * Function to get integers, that are entered by the user
     */
    unsigned int input;
    stream >> input;
    return input;            
}
```